# Redirect to another page from colorbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a colorbox. I want to redirect to another page after validating some value using php. I have tried the below code

```
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
    echo "<script>
        parent.$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ 
        window.location.href = 'paypal.php';
        }); parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); </script>";
}
```

But it is refreshing this iframe. I cant find the error. Could anyone tell me how i can do this.

Comment: to be clear you want an iframe content to change to location of its parent website?

Comment: Try window.top.location.href = 'paypal.php'

Comment: Where is the `parent` object coming from?

Comment: i want to close my iframe and go to another page

Comment: i have tried window.top.location.href, result is colorbox has been closed but not redirecting to paypal.php

Comment: is there any other way to redirect to another page

Comment: Are you trying to re-direct your iFrame to another page, or redirect the parent?

Comment: I am trying to redirect it to another page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window.top to reach the topmost window otherwise you will only reload the iframe:

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
    echo "<script>
    parent.$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ 
        window.top.location.href = 'paypal.php';
    }); parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using heredoc for echo, because PHP processes '$' in double quotes.
Also it should be state type of script - `<script type="text/javascript">`